# How to play video from MediaRecorder in Android

Tags: java, android, android-mediarecorder, android-video-player

I want develop one screen recorder application
I develop this and i can record from screen, but after stop recording when i want play this video, show me this **message** :

> Cannot play video. Unsupported file type

For record screen i used MediaProjectionManager, MediaProjection, MediaRecorder !

**My codes :**

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);

        videoUri = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                + new StringBuilder("/Rec_").append(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss").format(new Date()))
                .append(".mp4").toString();

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(videoUri);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(500 * 1000);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);

        int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int orientation = ORIENTATIONS.get(rotation + 90);
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(orientation);
        mediaRecorder.prepare();

    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Why not play my recorded videos? how can i fix it?

Comment: is your video file having size(not 0 bytes) ?

Comment: @RajasekaranM, no my friend, this file size is 40kb

Comment: is playing in normal player of your device?

Comment: do you received any error code try play video in your app?

Comment: @RajasekaranM, yes i play this with default player, and not show me any error in app!

Comment: is it played in default app?

Comment: @RajasekaranM, no . not play in any player

Comment: so video is corrupted that's why not played